# What is the difference between 'To study English is not easy' and 'Studying English is not easy'?

Tags: sentence, nuance

What is the difference (nuance) between these two sentences?

> 'To study English is not easy.'
>
> 'Studying English is not easy.'

Comment: The first is more apt to be followed by something like "But not studying English is even harder."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parth, that's not quite right. **To study** (the infinitive) and **studying** (the verbal noun) have the same function in the sentence so are semantically identical. In both sentences the subject is the noun clause, 'To study English' and 'Studying English', followed by the predicate, 'is not easy'. It's just the syntactical makeup of that noun clause that differs. So here the question is about connotation and about which is more natural in English.

The verbal noun is more natural here. Using the infinitive adds emphasis and suggests a different sort of meaning: like 'To study English is never an easy task', or 'To study English is a necessity these days'.